# how to turn off loading the layout in ZfcAdmin module for ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i'm trying to turn off the layout for some controllers in zfc-admin. Unfortunately all the methods i've found does the exact opposite. turns off the views and loads the layout.

Eg.

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
        return $viewModel;
```

Is something in the configuration of ZfcAdmin that disturbs the usual functionality of setTerminal() method ?

Comment: You are right. I have tested this with my own setup and I reckon this as a bug. I filed one and assigned it to myself: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin/issues/8. If you follow the issue you will be notified when I have resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution, following Jurian Sluiman comment, when you want to disable layout you can simply add a get parameter to the ( /?disableLayout=true) when you call a needed action, and in the layout

```
if (isset($_GET['disableLayout']) && $_GET['disableLayout'] == 'true') die();
```

or something similar (adjust to your needs)

Answer (score 1):

As another *temporary* solution, you can edit `ZfcAdmin\Module.php` to fix this bug. Change like this:

```
public function selectLayoutBasedOnRoute(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app    = $e->getParam('application');
    $sm     = $app->getServiceManager();
    $config = $sm->get('config');

    if (false === $config['zfcadmin']['use_admin_layout']) {
        return;
    }

    $match = $e->getRouteMatch();
    if (!$match instanceof RouteMatch || 0 !== strpos($match->getMatchedRouteName(), 'zfcadmin')) {
        return;
    }

    $layout     = $config['zfcadmin']['admin_layout_template'];
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    if( ! $controller->getEvent()->getResult()->terminate() ) // Add by Vinicius Garcia, to fix ->setTerminal() bug (https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin/issues/8)
        $controller->layout($layout);
}
```

Just add the `if( ! $controller->getEvent()->getResult()->terminate() )` before set the layout will solve the problem.

of course, It's a *bad practice* change code of a third-party module, but I guess it's better than include extra code in all your views that need this...

When ZF-Commons fix the bug you can just override the module, using their solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide in your question disables layout rendering and only outputs the view of the action.

Can you clarify your question..?